# ubuntu partition is nowhere to be found in dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual boot system, win7 in `sdb1` and ubuntu in `sdb6`, the latter resides on an extended partition.

well up until today, `update-grub2` would not find a windows partition and today I decide to try and fix that.

using the win7 install dvd, I used the dos cmd line to try and fix the error. the suggested methods within `askubuntu` said to use `bootsect /nt60 c:` and `bootrec /fixboot`. These failed for me and pursuing myattempts I also tried `bootrec /fixmbr`. Either that or a filesystem check from the win side, managed to make the ubuntu partition (sdb6) disappear completely.

How I see the full disk now:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf2eeea4d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    65383135    32690544    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2        65384446   117229567    25922561    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5        92069888   117229567    12579840   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

as you can see sdb6 is not even present any longer.
from `gparted` I can see that there exist unallocated space between sector #'s: `65384447 &  92069888`.

I tried using `gpart` to acquire actual sector # in order to then use `parted -> rescue` , but `gpart` returns wrong data:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gpart /dev/sdb

Begin scan...
End scan.

Checking partitions...
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

This could be related to the fact that MBR was last written from windows. I do not know how to proceed though.

Should I install grub now (even though there is no ubuntu partition) and try `gpart` again afterwards?
If yes, how should I go about it? is there a walk-through for that?
If no, what else is suggested to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `testdisk` utility , I was able to scan the disk and find the partition again.

`testdisk` is fairly easy to use, especially if you have an idea of the "partition map" of the disk.